# Zabbix: MySQL service monitor - invalid entry when restarting zabbix-agent

Tags: mysql, zabbix, zabbix-agent

Take the following situation:

- zabbixserver: httpd, mysql-server, zabbix 2.2.11 with local database
- databaseserver: mysql-server
- zabbixserver monitors the local mysql database correctly.
- zabbixserver reports that mysql on the databaseserver is down, while it is up
- zabbixserver reports for other services on the databaseserver work OK

I've done the following to get this working, following [this guide](http://blog.themilkyway.org/2013/11/how-to-monitor-mysql-using-the-new-zabbix-template-app-mysql/). On the databaseserver the zabbix-agent is installed, which reports to the zabbixserver.

- created zabbixuser with usage grants on all databases and flushed privileges
- created `/etc/zabbix/.my.cnf`

The file `/etc/zabbix/.my.cnf` is ignored. If I put it in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d` it is used.

```
[mysql]
user=zabbixuser
password=123456
[mysqladmin]
user=zabbixuser
password=123456
```

This .my.cnf has two profiles: mysql and mysqladmin, but I don't see where these are linked and why I should use these. Restarting the zabbix-agent results in an error.

> Starting Zabbix agent: zabbix_agentd [12334]: invalid entry [[mysql]] (not following "parameter=value" notation) in config file [/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d//.my.cnf], line 1

The `/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log` reports this:

```
1077:20151125:170718.508 active check configuration 
update from [10.2.3.4:10051] started to fail 
(cannot connect to [[10.2.3.4]:10051]: [4] Interrupted system call)
mysqladmin: unknown variable 'USER=zabbixuser'
mysql: unknown variable 'USER=zabbixuser'
```

**What is wrong with this configuration?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your configurations are:

1. You are putting the `.my.cnf` file at the wrong place.

Zabix agent configuration file has prescribed format and parameters defined. If you may use `Include` option to load additional config files, be sure it follows the same format. The zabbix [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/processes/zabbix_agentd) states it clearly:

> Starting from version 1.8.6 Zabbix agent daemon will not start up if
>   invalid (**not following parameter=value notation**) or unknown parameter
>   entry is present in configuration file.

So, in your case the `.my.cnf` file fails to load when you put it under `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d`.

- You are missing the part to configure `userparameter_mysql.conf` file properly.

**To resolve the issues:**

- Move the `.my.cnf` file from `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d` directory to `/etc/zabbix`. And also remove any `Include` entry to refere to the .my.cnf file (if there is any). The content of the file may look like this:

> ```
> [mysqld]
> user=username
> password=userpass
>
> [mysqladmin]
> user=username
> password=userpass
> ```

Please make sure that the user listed here exists and have the necessary permissions in mysql.

- Edit `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_mysql.conf` file:
  You need to replace `HOME=/var/lib/zabbix` with `HOME=/etc/zabbix` to point to the right file (should appear three times) as mentioned in the first line of the file.
- Finally restart the agent:    `service zabbix-agent restart`

Comment: Thanks. I changed the configuration like you suggested, but still it doesn't work. See the log report in my updated question.

Comment: It's working with the mysql/mysqladmin config. It turned out to be that the password for the user was wrong. Many thanks for helping out.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that it helped.